# How to get PayPal PDT if customer close the browser after completing payment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I have an e-commerce platform where customers are paying for the product. What we did for tracking customers details is auto-returning to our site with PDT (Payment Data Transfer). But recently we saw that some customers are closing the browser after completing their payment. So they are not auto redirected back to us. And we can't do further procedures. So what should we do in this scenario? How can we solve it?

Comment: You shouldn't rely on PDT for confirming  the payment. The user could close the window or not being redirected also due to a network error so you won't confirm the transaction. You should use IPN (or webhooks)

Comment: Yes, that's true. But sometimes it takes a long time to get ipn. So, i need the pdt to at least confirm the payment and let the user to do some further procedures.
I mean i want to do something in the success page after returning my site.

Comment: you are unfortunately right, sometimes it takes time to get the IPN. Unfortunately I think there isn't much you can do if the auto return is enabled properly

Comment: Yes, It's really unfortunate.

Answer (score 2):

An automatic return from an API-less Payments Standard integration is not guaranteed. Sometimes, notably in the case of a guest checkout, PayPal must show a receipt, and so the customer must manually click to return. Or the network connection could be interrupted, or their browser could crash. So relying on PDT to trigger business logic is a very bad idea.

Alternatives:

1. Wait for an asynchronous webhook: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/ -- or similarly (older solution), an asynchronous IPN: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/
2. Change from Payments Standard to a synchronous API-based server side integration, such as the one shown in this skeleton demo: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server . With this, the capture occurs from your server (after the browser executes the fetch command or redirect back to your server), so you get an immediate API response when your server does that API call to PayPal to capture the payment.